# Sending value of PHP variable to Javascript document

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

So I am trying to reach into a MySQL table and draw out a value. I have the following PHP that does so:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<?php
$username = strval($_GET['userName']);

$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','PRIVATE','PRIVATE','PRIVATE');
if (!$con) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
} else {
$sql="SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '".$username."'";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $wealth = $row['wealth'];
    echo $wealth;
    }
}

mysqli_close($con);
//return $wealth;
?></body>
</html>
```

I've put PRIVATE where the database ID and password go for security reasons. Essentially, this PHP takes the value out of the 'wealth' column in according to the logged on user. I have this AJAX function that triggers this PHP (the ajax is located inside of the document I would like to send the PHP variable to). Note that this function sends the username of the current logged on user and their 'score' (the var clicks) to the PHP.

```
function sendScore() {

$.post("sendScore.php",{username:localStorage.getItem('userName'),wealth:clicks},function(response){
   console.log("The service replied"+response);
});

}
```

Now, I know the value I retrieved is equal to the PHP variable $wealth. I also understand that PHP is server based and Javascript/html are client based, so you can't simply reach into another document and find the value of the variable. I'd like to assign the value of $wealth to a javascript variable named: userWealth

Thanks for reading!

EDIT: I WROTE THE Q WRONG ...

@Ilan Kleiman Small problem... I have two separate PHP files, sendScore and getScore. I had mistakenly pasted the wrong ones in the question. So, I have the sendScore AJAX which you can see in the question, but this triggers a different PHP code which isn't shown above, which essentially writes into the 'wealth' column. I have a separate piece of PHP, shown above, which is used to RETRIEVE written info from the wealth column (like how cookie clicker saves the number of clicks you have when you close the tab, this code activates when you open the website back up again, and it loads the last written value in 'wealth'). I am looking into how to create a piece of AJAX that can turn the $wealth PHP variable generated by the code into a javascript variable. Sorry for the confusion.

EDIT #2: CODE

AJAX FOR SENDSCORE

```
$.post("sendScore.php",{username:localStorage.getItem('userName'),wealth:clicks},function(response){
```

console.log("The service replied"+response);
    });

PHP FOR SENDSCORE

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<?php
$username = strval($_POST['username']);
$wealth = strval($_POST['wealth']);

$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','PRIV','PRIV','PRIV');
if (!$con) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
} else {

$sql = "UPDATE users SET wealth=".$wealth." WHERE username='".$username."'";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

}

mysqli_close($con);

?></body>
</html>
```

AJAX FOR GETSCORE IS WHAT I AM TRYING TO FIND

PHP FOR GETSCORE

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<?php
$username = strval($_GET['userName']);

$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','PRIV','PRIV','PRIV');
if (!$con) {
die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
} else {
$sql="SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '".$username."'";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
$wealth = $row['wealth'];
echo $wealth;
}
}

mysqli_close($con);
//return $wealth;
?></body>
</html>
```

Comment: you can do this with ajax

Comment: Can you help me with that?

Answer (score 0):

In your PHP file:

change

```
echo $wealth;
```

to

```
echo "<div id='wealth'>" . $wealth . "</div>";
```

AJAX Request:

```
var userWealth;
function getScore() {
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            userWealth = document.getElementById("wealth").innerHTML;
            alert(userWealth);
        }
    };
    xhttp.open("GET", "getScore.php", true);
    xhttp.send();
}
```

This will set "userWealth" to $wealth from the PHP.

Keep in mind, the Javascript should be on the same "server/website" as the PHP otherwise the AJAX request won't work.

Comment: Amazing. This is exactly what I am looking for. So, this sends the information, and it also makes userWealth equal to the value of PHP $wealth ? Does 'data' just target the last value outputted?

Comment: data is equal to the entire text outputted by your php page. I'm assuming the only output is $wealth since that's the code you posted @CasparBroekhuizen

Comment: I made a big mistake while writing the question.... please see the edited version above.

Comment: @CasparBroekhuizen I'm still a little confused by the process. I'll edit my answer

Comment: Confused... I have two PHP documents, one called getScore.php and one called sendScore.php. The one you see in the question above is getScore.php. I already have a working sendScore AJAX which triggers sendScore.php which then sends a value to the wealth column in the database. sendScore works, so lets leave it alone. SO, I have some PHP code called getScore (see above in the question) that takes a value from the 'wealth' column and outputs to echo $wealth. I need an AJAX function that then turns this echo into a javascript variable. A little confsued because your example has sendScore in it.

Comment: Ill attach the code in the question well labelled so you can see what I'm on about.

Comment: Thanks for your help by the way. Really appreciate it.

Comment: @CasparBroekhuizen I changed my answer only slightly, It should be working. I even added "alert(userWealth);" which you can remove later on.

I changed the function name to "getScore()" and the file it requests from to "getScore.php" make sure you change those as necessary


Make sure to change your getScore.php slightly where the $wealth is echo'd.

In my answer I changed echo $wealth; to echo "<div id='wealth'>" . $wealth . "</div>";

Comment: For reference, what does if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) mean?

Comment: @CasparBroekhuizen When a webpage responds to a browser or anything, it sends a number in the header. "200" means the page responded fine. "404" means the page wasn't found. "500" means there was an internal server error etc...

So if the page responded with "200 OK", then the script continues

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_xmlhttprequest_create.asp      

readyState Holds the status of the XMLHttpRequest.
0: request not initialized 
1: server connection established
2: request received 
3: processing request 
4: request finished and response is ready

Comment: Interesting... I integrated the script and created a button to run the getScore function, and nothing happened. So, I tested that the button was working fine by adding an alert() straight after the function as such: function getScore { alert()    - and the alert pops up, with 'userWealth' being undefined, of course. For some reason the if statement is not completing and the alert inside of it is not being triggered. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you change the PHP and add the "<div id='wealth'>".$wealth."</div>" ?

Comment: Yes. But even if I didn't, the if statement should still be triggering the alert to popup....

Comment: Are both the PHP and the getScore function hosted on the same website?

You can't send AJAX requests from different Domains

Comment: Yeah, true. Possibly you have it cross domains then^ read my prev comment

Comment: Both the files are hosted on the same website. Ah, so confusing. Are there any syntax errors?

Comment: You can see it in the edited question above. Sorry, was late, so left the computer for the night.

Comment: @CasparBroekhuizen sendScore is what you have posted. I thought getScore was what you didn't have working